# Git octopus merge order of multiple branches

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I had an interesting thing happen using git, wondering if anyone could explain it to me so I can understand better.

When doing a merge of multiple branches (A,B),

```
git merge A B
```

fails as non-fast-forward, while

```
git merge B A
```

worked well. Why would that be?

Comment: What kind of conflicts did you get? I think in general this is going to be because the change made by B made A easier to merge, e.g. A tried to patch a file which doesn't exist until it's renamed to that name in B.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Let's assume that A is a strict, [direct child](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) of the current branch. Then assume that B is a strict, direct child **of A**.

The octopus merge, which [processes heads given as arguments from left to right](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/git-merge-octopus.sh?id=v1.3.1), *incrementally with respect to the tree*, but *independently with respect to the index* succeeds without conflict if it tries to apply B and then A, but encounters a conflict if it does the converse.

As per the `git-merge` manual, section *MERGE STRATEGIES*:

```
octopus
   This resolves cases with more than two heads, but refuses to do a
   complex merge that needs manual resolution.
```

For instance:

```
 ~                 $ git init testdir && cd testdir && echo "This is C" > myfile
 Initialized empty Git repository in /home/huitseeker/testdir/.git/

 ~/testdir         $ git add myfile && git commit -m "C" 
 [master (root-commit) f0c8c82] C
  1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
  create mode 100644 myfile

 ~/testdir(master) $ git checkout -b "A" && echo "This is A1" > myfile
 Switched to a new branch 'A'
 ~/testdir(A)      $ git commit -m "A1" myfile
 [A ac5b51c] A1
  1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

 ~/testdir(A)      $ git checkout -b "B" && echo "This is B1" >> myfile
 Switched to a new branch 'B'
 ~/testdir(B)      $ git commit -m "B1" myfile
 [B 5bc838c] B1
  1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

 ~/testdir(B)      $ git checkout master
 Switched to branch 'master'
 ~/testdir(master) $ git merge B A
 Fast-forwarding to: B
 Already up-to-date with A
 Merge made by octopus.
  myfile |    3 ++-
  1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

 ~/testdir(master) $ git reset --hard HEAD^^^
 HEAD is now at f0c8c82 C
 ~/testdir(master) $ git merge A B
 Fast-forwarding to: A
 Fast-forwarding to: B
 error: Entry 'myfile' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.
 Merge with strategy octopus failed.

 ~/testdir(master) $ cat myfile
 This is A1
```

Indeed, when fast-forwarding to A, the label of master has not been pushed forward, though the tree has.

```
 ~/testdir(master) $ git status
 # On branch master
 # Changes to be committed:
 #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
 #
 #  modified:   myfile
 #
```

If, looking at the code of what the octopus merge does, I perform this manually (look above for hashes):

```
 ~/testdir(master) $ git reset --hard f0c8c82
 HEAD is now at f0c8c82 C     
 ~/testdir(master) $ git read-tree -u -m f0c8c82 ac5b51c
 ~/testdir(master) $ git read-tree -u -m f0c8c82 5bc838c
 error: Entry 'myfile' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.
```

In the other direction (`merge B A`), now, if you look again at the code of merge-octopus, it tries to detect the branch we are trying to add is already in the tree (second `case` of the `for` loop). Indeed, at the merge of A, it sees ac5b51c (a.k.a. A's head) is the common ancestor of A and B, and aborts without doing the second `read-tree`.

This behavior is consistent with the fresh version of git : though I've pointed to v.1.3.1, this is still happening with my version.

```
 ~/testdir(master) $ git --version
 git version 1.7.5.4
```

tl;dr : **you want your octopus merge branches to touch distinct files**

Comment: Your link doesn't really explain what you mean by direct upstream. My best guess is that you mean the merge would be a fast-forward, i.e. B is a "strict, direct upstream" of A means that A is an ancestor of B. In that case, your example doesn't work. In the first case, both merges are fast-forwards, and all is good, and in the second case, the first is a fast-forward and the second is already merged and therefore a no-op, not a cause of merge conflicts.

Comment: You are right, I was grossly imprecise. I have edited my answer to reflect your comments, added the crucial indication that octopus does not update the head index between merge applications, and included a minimal example.

Comment: Awesome, now that's an answer.