# git mergetool octopus

Tags: git

Say I have branches

```
master
dog
cat
```

Changes have been made on both `dog` and `cat`. When I merge these in

```
git checkout master
git merge dog cat
```

It creates a conflict because the people on `dog` and `cat` changed a file in different ways. I tried to resolve this issue using
[**kdiff3**](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net) but it doesn't seem to work with an "octopus" merge. Is this the case or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Related (and an awesome answer for all things octopus): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520905/git-octopus-merge-order-of-multiple-branches